# Activity start too long

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, application-start

Hello I have a problem with opening `Activity`.

I'm calling `startActivity()` with `Intent` by clicking `Button`.

I need to wait 4-5 seconds before `Activity` shows up on the screen.

I know how to do.

```
itemimg = new ItemsInPacagesImageView(imglist1, this, nazovtripu, 0);
```

I have 17 times similar code (with other `ImageView`s) I have this in Method with name  `InitItemimg();`

I tried put this method on OnStart activity with this thread

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    timer = new Thread() { // new thread
        public void run() {
            Boolean b = true;
            try {
                sleep(20);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                               InitItemimg();;
                            }

                        });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();

}
```

But is no resolve my problem, please do you have some ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

excuse me, I figured so in this method (`ItemsInPacagesImageView(imglist1, this, nazovtripu, 0);`) on start id deserialization if is some deserialization in row is "fast" but if it's more in row (now 17) with deserialization program spend more time some seconds.

I resolve this problem with put explicit, class which i deserialization in method.

Now i deserialization once instead 17 times. and I safe more miliscond-seconds.